# What's the full form of value "_MCW_EM" in Windows API function

Tags: winapi

_MCW_EM is used on floating point calculation exception, the "EM" must be "exception mask", but what is the full form of "MCW"?

Comment: It is not a winapi function, it is a [helper function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx) in the Microsoft CRT.  Just read the docs for the valid masks and values.  And *never* use it, enabling exceptions is drastically incompatible with most any library code.

Answer (score 1):

- `M`: Marks
- `C`: Control
- `W`: Word

Thus, `_MCW_EM` means The **error masks** of control word marks.

check the comments of [MinGW Source Code](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/bin/MinGW/include/float.h)